# How to convert Feature to Python object?

Tags: tensorflow

I have some `Example`s stored in files in binary format which I am reading 
like this:

```py
for fp in shard_filepaths:
    record_iterator = tf.python_io.tf_record_iterator(path=fp)
    for record in record_iterator:
         example = tf.train.Example.FromString(record)
```

Is there a way to map the `example` into a Python `dict` or `object`?

I know I could do something like

```py
data = json.loads(MessageToJson(tf.train.Example.FromString(record)))
```

but that will produce a rather complex and unhandy output.

What are my options here?

---

In addition, this is the method (see tensor2tensor [`to_example(dictionary)`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensor2tensor/blob/v.1.12.0/tensor2tensor/data_generators/generator_utils.py#L42)) that generated the records from a `dict` to an `example`:

```py
def to_example(dictionary):
    """Helper: build tf.Example from (string -> int/float/str list) dictionary."""

    features = {}

    for (k, v) in six.iteritems(dictionary):
        if not v:
            raise ValueError('Empty generated field: %s' % str((k, v)))
        if isinstance(v[0], six.integer_types):
            features[k] = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=v))
        elif isinstance(v[0], float):
            features[k] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=v))
        elif isinstance(v[0], six.string_types):
            if not six.PY2:  # Convert in python 3.
                v = [bytes(x, 'utf-8') for x in v]
            features[k] = tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=v))
        elif isinstance(v[0], bytes):
            features[k] = tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=v))
        else:
            raise ValueError('Value for %s is not a recognized type; v: %s type: %s' % (k, str(v[0]), str(type(v[0]))))

    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=features))
```

Comment: How would you like your dictionary to look? and how does the variable example looks?

Comment: @anand_v.singh I'd like to have a dictionary where each key maps to the corresponding feature list. Actually I'd prefer a python `object` over a `dict` but I don't know if that's how `Example`s are intended to be used for. The problem is that the values are either of type `float_list` or `int64_list` and yes, I could simple go through `data` here and get all the values I need but this just does not feel like something *I* should do myself - but I cannot find a method to generate a usable output.

Comment: So If I am understanding correctly you want each record mapped with the corresponding example it generates so that if you have the record value you can directly access the examples value that you obtained, and theoretically the records are unique.

Comment: @anand_v.singh Yes, and yes, the records are unique. Each record actually was generated from a dict. I'll add that part of the code to my question.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is a dictionary comprehension, suppose you want to call your dictionary as lookup.

```
lookup = {record:tf.train.Example.FromString(record) for record in record_iterator}
```

After this simply `lookup[record]` will give you the corresponding example.

That should get the job done, do let me know whether this works or not.

Happy Coding.

Comment: This is just a map from example to record. If you look at my question you see that I am already using `FromString` but declared it as too cumbersome to use.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand this is what you are looking for, you will need to modify the variable names but this should get the job done.

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(['filename.tfrecord'])

_, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

# Define features
read_features = {
    'Feature 1': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
    'Feature 2 tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.string),
    'Feature 3: tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
    'Feature 4: tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
    'Feature 5: tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32),
    'Feature 6: tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.float32)}

# Extract features from serialized data
read_data = tf.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized_example,
                                    features=read_features)
```

read_data will be a list output.